# Html Css responsive problem on live host server

Tags: html, css, localhost, responsive, host

When I code my HTML CSS code and make it responsive everything is okay and design fine in localhost but when I transfer that code to live server host my responsive design gonna mess up.
Thank You.

Comment: There may be multiple reasons for this. I suggest you add more details or code so we can help you. The first example that comes to mind might be a css file that cannot be loaded properly. `localhost/path/any.css` to `hostname/path/any.css`

Comment: Okay thank you so much i will check it its not work again I will share the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello to StackOverflow firstly! We usually add the code we wrote to question. So we can help you faster. But I have some ideas, let me share them:

- When you use local server, you must clear caches if you have external CSS/JS files. If you are using Chrome, just press `CTRL+F5`
- When you move your project to `localhost`, there could be mess the libraries you used. I don't know but if you're using libraries in your project, move them to your local server and don't forget to update script locations from your `index` file.

Comment: Okay thank you so much i will check it its not work again I will share the code.